# Trouble typing a sum type with generics and overloads

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading, either

I am trying to type an implementation of Either and I struggle to make the two variants play well with each other.

First, the implementation:

```js
type Unary<X, R> = (x: X) => R;
type Either<L=unknown, R=unknown> = Left<L> | Right<R>

class Right<R=unknown> {
    constructor (private value: R) {}

    static of <T>(value:T):Right<T> { return new Right(value); }

    map <U>(f:Unary<R, U>):Right<U> {
        return Right.of(f(this.value));
    }

    ap <T>(either: Left<T>): Left<T>
    ap <U>(either: Right<Unary<R, U>>): Right<U>
    ap <T, U>(either: Either<T, Unary<R, U>>): Either<T, U> {
        return either instanceof Left
            ? either
            : this.map(either.value);
    }
}

class Left<L=unknown> {
    constructor (private value: L) {}

    static of <T>(value:T):Left<T> { return new Left(value); }

    map (_:Function): Left<L> { return this; }

    ap <T>(either: Left<T>): Left<T>
    ap (either: Right): Left<L>
    ap (either: Either): Left { 
        return either instanceof Left ? either : this;
    }
}
```

On the surface, everything appears to be working fine both at runtime and compile time:

```js
const r1 = Right.of(1);
const r2 = Right.of(2);
const l1 = Left.of(Error('foo'));
const l2 = Left.of(Error('bar'));

const add = (a:number) => (b:number) => a + b

// Right { value: 3 } : Right<number>
const rr = r2.ap(r1.map(add));

// Left { value: [Error: foo] } : Left<Error>
const lr = r2.ap(l1.map(add));

// Left { value: [Error: bar] } : Left<Error>
const rl = l2.ap(r1.map(add));

// Left { value: [Error: foo] } : Left<Error>
const ll = l2.ap(l1.map(add));
```

...but it falls apart if I try to define a lift function.

```js
const lift2 = <A, B, R>(f:(a: A) => (b: B) => R) => {
    function lifted(a:Right<A>, b:Right<B>): Right<R>
    function lifted<U>(a:Right<A>, b:Left<U>): Left<U>
    function lifted<T>(a:Left<T>, b:Right<B>): Left<T>
    function lifted<T>(a:Left<T>, b:Left): Left<T>
    function lifted(a: Either, b: Either):Either {
        return b.ap(a.map(f));
        //          ------=-
    }
    return lifted;
}
```

I have 2 distinct errors

```
Argument of type 'Left<unknown> | Right<(b: B) => R>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Left<unknown>'.
  Type 'Right<(b: B) => R>' is not assignable to type 'Left<unknown>'.
    Types have separate declarations of a private property 'value

The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.
```

```
Argument of type '(a: A) => (b: B) => R' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Unary<unknown, (b: B) => R> & Function'.
  Type '(a: A) => (b: B) => R' is not assignable to type 'Unary<unknown, (b: B) => R>'.
    Types of parameters 'a' and 'x' are incompatible.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'A'.
        'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'
```

Oddly enough, the correct types are inferred on the call site:

```js
const add = lift2(
    (a:number) => (b:number) => a + b
);

// Right { value: 3 } : Right<number>
const rr = add(r1, r2);

// Left { value: [Error: foo] } : Left<Error>
const lr = add(l1, r2);

// Left { value: [Error: bar] } : Left<Error>
const rl = add(r1, l2);

// Left { value: [Error: foo] } : Left<Error>
const ll = add(l1, l2);
```

- I don't know why `Left<unknown>` is inferred for the type parameter
- I don't know where the `unknown` in `Unary<unknown, (b: B) => R>` comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest making the implementation signature of `lifted()` more precise... perhaps something like this:

```
function lifted<T, U>(
  a: Either<T, A>, 
  b: Either<U, B>
): Either<U, R> | Left<T> {...};
```

This should make any problems involving `unknown` go away... your original types for `a` and `b` were just `Either` which is `Either<unknown, unknown>` (thanks to [generic type parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)), and the compiler is right to complain that you can't pass `unknown` to something that expects an `A`.

In fact, I'd suggest making the full set of signatures as precise as possible, and not let `unknown` creep in anywhere it doesn't need to:

```
    function lifted(a: Right<A>, b: Right<B>): Right<R>
    function lifted<U>(a: Right<A>, b: Left<U>): Left<U>
    function lifted<T, U>(a: Left<T>, b: Either<U, B>): Left<T>
    function lifted<T, U>(a: Either<T, A>, b: Either<U, B>): Either<U, R> | Left<T> {
        // impl to come
    }
    return lifted;
```

---

Next, the compiler is not smart enough to see that `b.ap(a.map(f))` is correct, because it treats `a` and `b` as two `Either` types, which are unions.  And while it turns out that `b.ap(a.map(f))` will always work no matter whether `a` or `b` is `Left` or `Right`, there is no single call signature for `Either.map` or `Either.ap` which is obviously correct to the compiler.  `Either` is a union type, and its `ap` and `map` methods are therefore unions of functions... and overloaded functions, to boot.  The compiler cannot resolve call signatures in an intelligent way for all these unions-of-overloads.  This is similar to the problem I have with what I've been calling *correlated union types* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)).

If the compiler were to re-evaluate `b.ap(a.map(f))` for each of the four possibilities for `a` and `b`, it would be happy with each one.  But since you only have one line, the compiler only considers it one time.  There is no such thing as "[control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) which distributes over unions" (see [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) for a closed request for such functionality, which would fix this if it were implemented.)

---

Without such abilities, you have two basic options:

1: use something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler not to worry about type safety for that line, for example:

```
return (b as any).ap(a.map(f)); // uses any here
```

This places the burden of type safety on you, so you need to be careful.  It is the most convenient option, though.

2: use redundant code to walk the compiler through the different possibilities for which it *is* able to verify type safety:

```
const aMapF = a.map(f);
return aMapF instanceof Left ? b.ap(aMapF) :
  b instanceof Left ? b.ap(aMapF) :
    b.ap(aMapF);
```

This is completely type safe, and the compiler sees that because control flow analysis allows narrowing of union-typed things to singly-typed things.  Of course, you pay for this safety with redundantly repetitive redundancy.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgQwE4gDwA0A0UBKA+KAXigAoAPALinQEoiCcBuAKFEigFEBLYACwiSoAMkSgBXOAGs4AewDucbDlETp8uAWJCIAM2DCCAH1xcA5r335mzAMYAbBAGdHJ85ZVTZCggG9mUAKgbGThHYCQxG2AZJBIwJC4ANwRgaGS7MQgqHDofKABfa0CoMJSuGygZHVQAFTwSdMyqGppsswta3ygkCGAxJDgoOAg5VwsGhAyIGkYCosCAWwQwVBh6nSp4ZDQcbDXWsf01qD9i4p6+gcOAOiqSHRI+LkdrxumZ-0DCz4DlzpIIDx+EgqNo9J0DmD9HUflA-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-qJA7ZrzE6zqW2oyRW1lgThqA1oB6kgZgEGDkRgRgdwIxwrqTkVSgVSoyuIi4RcUUQBoSqEGS+46sHIJbIQABZZZM1EBnUx0A1B3JwYOa5sdSjFCUdDUmc6PpzmwEzOgKBJ4ooLFkUJancMZaguWuaVlXB11tz5cV5cvlhIWFvOlg10QBYIEcMAEHFKAakdv04FMKbWcQlC4rOs8SBJlaBLIoaiJIwTyMmqjaPo4p4OKVStvUzKmi4ni230MOhNhBqxOIBTpK3bBzyTwJ0u1nysv8vSqAM-KnoivTwcCBq7HsouUKq0vulvZTk686v044uuYioIKm-Cor89smKeZ7mTsHiiuAirvRWM08fcqM0zm9n21bNKxflqfFeB+sQogA)

Comment: My hero! Defaulting to `unknown` was a very bad idea, I will avoid it in the future. I am eager to find ways to reduce the amount of type-annotation code I need to write, or to find type-level reusable abstractions, for it distracts me a lot. We just turned a one line obviously correct abstract function into a ~10 lines long non-trivial concrete function, not to mention that unit test should double-check everything we did. I expressed a similar discomfort in code review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259632/generic-object-mapping-function) if you want to have a look.

Comment: I also really appreciate your investment in improving the language